# class com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap cannot be cast to class

Tags: java, arraylist, gson, fromjson

I'm having troubles to retrieve an object from a json (using gson).

Here is the object's class attributs :

```
abstract class Table {
    protected ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>> table;
    protected String requete;
```

I put this object in a ArrayList then in a json like this :

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
ArrayList<Table> buffer = new ArrayList<Table>();
buffer.add(this);
try (FileWriter file = new FileWriter(nomTest)) {
            gson.toJson(buffer, file);
```

Then I try to retrieve the data :

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
ArrayList<Table> reponses = null;
FileReader reader = new FileReader(nomTest))
reponses = (ArrayList<Table>) gson.fromJson(reader, new ArrayList<Table>().getClass());
Table buffer = reponses.get(numQuestion-1); //ERROR CAST
```

But here I get

```
class com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap cannot be cast to class evaluateur.Table
```

I could not find a solution in my case.

Thanks for the help.

EDIT1 :

Here is the JSON (don't mind the 2 same objects) :

```
[
   {
      "table":[[2.0,"Alain","Verse"],[7.0,"Pierre","Kiroul"]],
      "requete":"SELECT * FROM test WHERE age \u003e 40"
   },
   {
      "table":[[2,"Alain","Verse"],[7,"Pierre","Kiroul"]],
      "requete":"SELECT * FROM test WHERE age \u003e 40"
   }
]
```

When i use `System.out.println(reponses.get(numQuestion-1));` it gives me `{table=[[2.0, Alain, Verse], [7.0, Pierre, Kiroul]], requete=SELECT * FROM test WHERE age > 40}`

I'd like to retrieve these "table" and "requete".

Comment: can you post the sample json and expected output

Comment: I think unrelated but `new ArrayList<Table>().getClass()` is not doing what you think it's doing. I think you're trying a workaround to get a `Class<ArrayList<Table>>` but that's not how it works. It will just return `Class<ArrayList>`. So `ArrayList.class` is the preferred way to get this value, since it is both shorter, faster and does not involve instantiating an object needlessly.

Comment: @Michael Thx for the insight, at the beginning i wrote this `Class.forName("java.util.ArrayList")` but tried different things as i was desperate.
It gave me the same exception btw.

Comment: @Lapinou Check out the linked duplicate